# Java, Spring, Tomcat, hangs at "INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext", I think I changed the allowed memory heap for my entire system

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, memory-management, heap-memory

I was playing around with the Java memory heap allocation and I think I did something that set it not just for any specific tomcat folder but for the entire system as I can't run my application in Spring or with a custom tomcat folder that I had been also using for testing. When I try to run the application, it just hangs at "INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext".

I am not fully clear on how I could have set this on the Linux command line by doing something like `"export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2000m -Xmx4500m"` or `"JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2000m -Xmx4500m -XX:MaxPermSize=4500m"`

I think I accidentally put the settings I had meant for my cloud server (which has a higher amount of memory) so I gave it more memory allocation than my entire system has.

I would appreciate any help if anyone can let me know if it is possible I did this and if this could be causing the issue and how I can get an output from my system as to the current allocation so I can check / change it, I have tried `"export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2000m -Xmx4500m"` but it still won't work for me.

I would like to restore everything to default settings. I normally set the memory heap allocation in the /bin/startup.sh file in the tomcat folder but I had forgotten this, I think, and was experimenting with things on the command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check all of the log files for Tomcat. It's possible that the startup of the Spring WebApplicationContext is encountering errors, but logging it elsewhere.

Setting the max heap size too large for Tomcat sounds like a red herring to me. If the initial heap size argument is larger than the maximum size of memory on the system, the Java process will fail immediately - Tomcat will not get to the point of initializing your Spring application.

Comment: I am checking them but I can't seem to find anything relevant, it just has the last line as "INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext"]

Comment: For anyone else wondering about this my problem was i entered my DB password wrong and it was hanging for a long time trying to connect.

Comment: For me, it happened because a database I was trying to connect to was temporarily unavailable.  (container-provided database, referenced via spring).

Comment: For me, it was missing application.properties and log4j.properties config files.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can increase the server timeout if you are running it from an IDE. From command line, you'll have to wait.
If the problem persists, try cleaning /reloading the application

Answer (score 0):

Isn't finding bugs what debuggers are for? Why not simply start your Tomcat in debug mode, wait until it "hangs", and find out what it is doing by suspending the relevant thread and looking at the stack trace?

Or even simpler, do a "thread dump" once the app hangs?

Comment: ok I will try that but if I didn't make it clear in my initial post: there isn't anything wrong with the app, its my server setup, I am able to build the app locally and then run it on my ec2 server

Comment: I tried that as well but its the same problem, it can't even startup at all so running it in debug mode is irrelevant as it can't run the app at all, it is hanging on "INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext"

Comment: I think doing a thread dump (kill -3 on unix) is a very reasonable thing to try. Give it a go, and you will see where your thread is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was another service that was not reachable

- spring was retrying again and again to reach and wating until it timeouts
- Once I started another service it worked automatically.